# Canonical Cover for Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I'm learning, or trying to learn about DBMS and am having all sorts of problems understanding how to compute a canonical cover for this:

```
A -> BCD
BC -> DE
B -> D
D -> A
```

I can only ever find 1 example of how to compute one of these and it doesn't help me understand what to do with the BC and B dependencies. This is what I came up with, which is surely wrong, but any help with breaking this down so I can understand would be more valuable than the actual answer.

```
A -> BCD
BC -> DE
D -> A
```

Comment: Does your textbook have an algorithm?

Comment: no, it just gives an example like the one of this site (see #5): http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chap5/node15.html

Comment: this is the same example in the textbook and is the only one I can find really. I understand it for the most part, but it doesn't really explain for the problem I have above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to look at the two FDs

- BC -> DE, and
- B -> D

From BC->DE, derive BC->D and BC->E (decomposition).

```
BC->D
BC->E
B->D
```

Observe that the LHS of BC->D is reducible, because B->D. That reduces the two FDs at the top to

```
BC->E
B->D
```

Comment: What is the justification for the last step?

Comment: The LHS of BC->D is reducible. Informally, BC->D doesn't tell us anything we don't already know from B->D. Formally, starting with B->D, we know BC->DC (augmentation) and BC->D (decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

this BC->D is reducible, because in BC->D,in left C is an extraneous attribute. we can check this by using the formula for extraneous attribute.

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer i think is:

```
a->bc
bc->e
b->d
d->a
```

to see if u can remove a relation or not , lets say we are considering the relation R1=a->b
calculate the F+(a) without considering the R1 relation itself . if u can still somehow get to b ( b is in F+(a) ) then u can remove R1

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
F = { 
  A -> BCD, 
  BC -> DE, 
  B -> D, 
  D -> A 
}
```

`D` is an extraneous attribute in `A -> BCD`,
because `A+ = ABCDE` and `D` belongs to `A+`

Hence :

```
Fc = { 
  A -> BC, 
  BC -> DE, 
  B -> D, 
  D -> A
}
```

Now `C` is an extraneous attribute in `BC -> DE`,
because `B+ = ABCDE` and `DE` belongs to `B+`

Hence:

```
Fc = { 
  A -> BC, 
  B -> DE, 
  B -> D, 
  D -> A
}
```

Now `D` is an extraneous attribute in `B -> DE`,
because `B+ = ABCDE` and `D` belongs to `B+`

Hence:

```
Fc = { 
  A -> BC, 
  B -> E, 
  B -> D, 
  D -> A
}
```

Using Union rule we get:

```
Fc = { 
  A -> BC, 
  B -> DE, 
  D -> A
}
```

Now there are no more extraneous attributes.
Hence This is the final canonical cover of `F`.